# Add form fields to single model form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model called Application, and I need users to be able to add their classes and grades  to a column in the database. Is there a way to do this without creating a separate model?

I need users able to press "Add Grades" as many times as they like, creating two new form fields to enter in the class name and grade they got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend creating a grades model - it is the Rails way. A Grade can belong to an Application. An Application can have many Grades. Each Grade can then have two attributes - a class and a grade.

Alternatively, you can store all your grades for a single application in a single column, but you'll be responsible for the format that they're saved in, ensuring that they are serialized at some point prior to being saved, parsing when you load each Application, etc. Finally, you'll be coming up with additional fields to deal with the parsed grades.

All of this can be avoided by simply creating the Grade model and setting up the appropriate relationship with the Application model.

Comment: What kind of association would this be? The grade model would obviously belong_to the application model. But would the application model has_many grades? or just has_one?